# Android Studio Media Player Issue

Tags: javascript, loops, arraylist, android-mediaplayer

I am having issues with running a List through the media player function. Each variable in the list has been hardcoded to correspond to an audio URL for a specific note and I'm using a *for* loop to loop through the list. I am able to pass the list without any errors and I've used the logcat to confirm the list is being looped through (each individual URL is printed in correct order) however the media player only plays the first note or URL of the list. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is better approach if I'm trying to play multiple audio files in a specific order. I appreciate any advice and feedback!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsGxx.png)